Debugging ROS 2 node with Gazebo in VS Code - Stopping the simulation on breakpoint
I am developing a ROS 2 node for a quadrotor controller. The quadrotor is simulated using Gazebo and it employs the PX4 autopilot.
I am using VSCode as the code editor and I am using the ROS extension debugging feature (ROS launch).
I am using the sim_time in the ROS 2 node so I think that when Gazebo stops the ROS 2 node does also. I was wondering if it is possible to stop the Gazebo simulation whenever the debugger reaches a breakpoint, and if so how to do it.
Thank you in advance,
Riccardo
